# how to add an array to a menu

Tags: android

i have some simple code below and it works for the most part. What it does now is create 5 different menus for the first 5 elements in my array, and then the rest of the elements show up in a little scrollable selection of menus.

How can i make it so that ALL of the elements in my array appear in the scrollable selection of menus?

thanks!

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

 for(int i = 0; i<ARRAY.length; i++)
     {
         menu.add(ARRAY[i]);

     }
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add menu by using `menu.add(..)` and you can set id for the `menu.add(0, id ,...)` second paramter and you can set label `menu.add(...., ARRAY[i])`

```
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        for(int i = 0; i<ARRAY.length; i++)
        {
             int id = i;
             menu.add(0,id,0,ARRAY[i]);
        }
        return true;
}
```

you can access this menu and perform operations using `onOptionsItemSelected()`

```
   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch(item.getItemId())
        {
           case 0:
                  //code goes here when you press the menu with id 0
                  break;
           case 1:
                  //code goes here when you press the menu with id 1
                  break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: some explanation would be nice, what is this supposed to do?

Comment: I know how to do this, but how can i make all the elements in my array appear in the overflow menu?

Comment: For that, you should use actionbar sherlock library for overflow menu.

Comment: It will appear as a overflow menu